# Module '"@angular/material/"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'

Tags: angular

Recently, I upgraded my angular from 6 to 16. After the update, I am getting an issue like "Module '"@angular/material/"' has no exported member 'MatSnackBar'".
Please help me out to fix this in my whole project. Thanks in advance.

I tried the "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" command to install the library.

Comment: Can you share the code for your module? I believe you should be importing `MatSnackBarModule` from '@angular/material/snack-bar'.

Comment: V6 to V16 is a huge jump. Did you check if there are any migration guides?

Comment: Most likely you have to change the import to `MatSnackBarModule`. Docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api)

Comment: How did you perform your upgrade? If you didn't use `ng update`, then you will likely run into several problems due to missing out on migrations. Using `ng update` will also force you to one major version at a time. One other thing, sometimes you will need to remove your `.angular` folder and your `node_modules` folder and run `npm i` (not `npm ci`) after an upgrade. This has solved some very strange bugs for me in the past.